# Поиск в тексте конструкции слово1|слово2|слово3 через regExp

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Как встроить regExp в js для того, чтобы найти в тексте конструкцию слово1|слово2|слово3 и вернуть массив [слово1, слово2, слово3]?
Насколько смог разобраться регулярное выражение должно выглядить как: `(\b\w+[|]\w+\B)`

Comment: сначала ищите всю конструкцию целиком чем то вроде `(\w+\|)+\w+` а потом разбиваете ее на массив с помощью split

Comment: Если вы ищете точное совпадение, то рег. выражения вам не нужны. [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) вам в помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если всегда три слова, то можно воспользоваться следующим регулярным выражением: `/(\w+)\|(\w+)\|(\w+)/`

```
var regexp = /(\w+)\|(\w+)\|(\w+)/;

var getResult = function (str, regexp) {
    var result = str.match(regexp);
    return result ? result[0].split('|') : [];
};

getResult('some text foo|bar|baz some text', regexp); // ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
getResult('foo|bar|baz', regexp) // ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
getResult('some text', regexp) // []
```

Если количество слов неизвестно, то можно воспользоваться более общим рег. выражением `(\w+\|)+(\w+)`.

И да, как написал @hindmost, если слова заданы заранее (например нужно определить, есть ли они в тексте), то можно воспользоваться методом [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).